# Error filebeat from Windows machine to vmware Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to send logs from filebeats (in a windows machine) to logstash (in a vmware ubuntu machine)
but I got this error:

```
Connecting error publishing events (retrying): dial tcp 192.168.220.130:5044: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

The configuration is : 
filebeat.yml in a windows machine:

```
output: 
   logstash:
      hosts: ["192.168.220.130:5044"]
   index : filebeat
   console:
   pretty: true
   worker: 1
```

logstash.config in a vmware ubuntu machine :

```
input {
   lumberjack {
        port => 5044 
        type => beats
        ssl_certificate => "/etc/ssl/logstash.pub"
        ssl_key => "/etc/ssl/logstash.key"
     }
}
```

or

```
input {
    beats {
    type => beats
    port => 5044
    }
}
```

Any tips ?
And i am using the Bridge network
I tried the same config internally in a vmware ubuntu machine and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error.
I had 2 different problem:

1 - The vmware was using `NAT Network` I switched to `Bridge Network`

2 - The elasticsearch configuration was only for `localhost`, I changed the configuration and it is working.